# Почему не применяется стиль к элементу?

Tags: html, css

Кто подскажет, в чем ошибка?

```
<a href="#" class="test" class="current" >
    <li id="a2">
        <img src="images/razrab.png" alt="home" class="menu-znak1" id="menu-znak1-1"/>
        <span class="stroka">Разработки</span>
        <div class="activ">
        <span>7</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</a>
```

---

```
.current #a2 {
    background: url(images/current1.png) no-repeat center;
    color: #f14134;
}
```

Вот так это должно выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаю, что ошибка мелкая и глупая, но не помешает свежий взгляд.

Comment: а как сейчас выглядит?

Comment: @BOPOH - если хочешь правильно ответить на вопрос - угадай (викторина-соревнование).

Comment: а сейчас выглядит как пункт меню вверху и внизу, то есть "контакты" "любимая музыка"
Цвет шрифта не изменен, фон ячейки тоже

Comment: Вопросы должны быть **текстом** а не картинкой и не ссылкой.

Comment: А вам больше одной ссылки тут и не нужно, картинка нужна всего одна, остальное -- код. Приведите в нормальный вид

Comment: верстальщик 99 level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените

```
<a href="#" class="test" class="current">
```

на

```
<a href="#" class="test current">
```